# Where can I find an example burn-down / planning game template?

Tags: templates, project-management, project-planning

I'd like to experiment with burn-down and planning game with the team I'm on.  People on my team are interested in making it happen, however I'm sure someone has done this before and has learned some lessons we hopefully don't have to repeat.  Does anyone know of an example Excel (or other tool) template available for burn-down or planning game activities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This MSDN Blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/progressive_development/archive/2008/02/19/motley-says-what-are-we-burning-down-your-house-scrum-part-v.aspx) Has quite a good review of using burndowns in combination with Cumulative Flow Diagrams which fleshes out the diagrams even more. In the resources links at the bottom of the article there is a [link to the Microsoft Scrum kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=98602&clcid=0x409) which has a pre-built excel file.

Answer (score 1):

yes I answered this somewhere else but we use tools just to generate burndown charts.
Like this one: http://www.burndown-charts.com

For the rest, a real board, some post-its and good will do wonders.

And for that tool they also [manage teams](http://www.burndown-charts.com/teams/dreamteam) and allow readonly view of the chart so you can show it to your manager:D .